# jpeg в код - получил "qq\xe6/\xeb\x89\xb8\x1b\x11\xa4\x9e\xff", что это за кодировка?

Tags: python, jpeg

у меня есть  123456.jpeg файл  и я с ним сделал следующее:

```
with open('123456.jpg','rb') as fil:
    byte = fil.read()

print(byte)
with open('23.txt','w') as fil:
    fil.write(str(byte))
```

получил  очень много  вот такого шифра:

```
x93\xfc$J\xd4\x1aQ\xb1.\x05\x05\x06\x05y\xda;6\xb0\x01\xd0+\xf4\x89\x05X\xb9\xa0\xd9\xd5y \xf4\x8eY\x16\xa6\xd5\xfd.\xef|3\xf2?,\xfc_\xd5\x05\xf39\xbet\xcf\x7f\xfe\xf3\xdf\xff\x00\xbc\n2\xd8$}_\xd7m@H\x1eI=\xff\x00\xfb\xcc qq\xe6/\xeb\x89\xb8\x1b\x11\xa4\x9e\xff\x00\xfd\xe7\xbf\xff\x00y\xef\xff\x00\xde2R6\xabk\xfa\xech\x90a\xe4\x0cR\x8cU\xd5\xf5\x7f\\\x18ub\xf7\xce\x99\xef\xff\x00\xde{\xff\x00\xf7\x8a\xd0,\r\x1fW\xf5\xc8O\x14\xac\xdf\xa4\xf7\xff\x00\xef\x13l\xc3G\xa2\xfe\xbb~"@\xf5\'\xbf\xff\x00y\xef\xff\x00\xde\x12\x0e\xa4"y_\xeb\x88\x00\x00\x0
```

у меня 2 вопроса:
 - что это за кодировка ? (имею ввиду `...........\xf4\x8eY\x16\xa6\xd5\xfd.\xef|3\.................`)
 - как  конвертировать это  `\xf4\x8eY\x16\xa6\xd5\xfd.\xef|3\` обратно в  .jpeg файл ?

Comment: А зачем вы с ним сделали это? Просто ничего не делайте, и никаких кодировок не будет. `with open('23.jpg', 'wb') as fil: fil.write(byte)`

Comment: Строка экранированных шестнадцатиричных представлений байтов.

Answer (score 0):

Байтовая кодировка.
Чтобы такую расшифровать, можно воспользоваться **b"строка-в-байтовом-представлении".decode("utf-8")** что вернёт строку в правильной кодировке - **utf-8**
Но там скорей всего будет что то не понятное. Ведь это обычные байты.
Чтобы превратить данные в .jpeg файл, просто запишем их в байтовой кодировке, ведь формально это он и есть, только в вот таком представлении:

```py
with open('23.jpeg','wb') as fil:
    fil.write(byte)
```

Вот и всё, получаем нормальную картинку.